# error 'Firebase is not defined' in online IDE (Firebase javascript client script-tag included)

Tags: firebase, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to follow the Web Quickstart on Firebase found [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html#) but I get stuck on step 2.

I set up a new webpage on [Cloud9](http://c9.io), using the HTML5 template, with following basic conent:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        "Hallo"
        <script>
            var Firebase = require("firebase");
            var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://resplendent-heat-2801.firebaseio.com/");
            myFirebaseRef.set({
              title: "Hello World!",
              author: "Firebase",
              location: {
                city: "San Francisco",
                state: "California",
                zip: 94103
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I don't add the line `var Firebase = require("firebase");` I get error

> 'Firebase is not defined'.

If I add the line I get the error:

> 'uncaught reference error: require is not defined.

I also tried to use a nodeJS template and then run command 
`$ npm install firebase --save` in the terminal. Result shows in terminal:

> firebase@2.4.0 node_modules/firebase
>
> └── faye-websocket@0.9.3 (websocket-driver@0.5.2)

(so installing firebase seems to work) and then add this page of code but that doesn't make a difference.

How to solve this issue? I do not have the option to install nodeJS locally (working on schoolcomputer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `require`. Firebase loads correctly from CDN.

Make sure you check security tab and add appropriate rules for write operations.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        "Hallo"
        <script>
            //var Firebase = require("firebase");
            var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://resplendent-heat-2801.firebaseio.com/");
            myFirebaseRef.set({
              title: "Hello World!",
              author: "Firebase",
              location: {
                city: "San Francisco",
                state: "California",
                zip: 94103
              }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the Firebase project on firebase.com and paste in the 'Add Firebase to your web app' JavaScript to your Cloud9 project.
2. Open a terminal at the root of your project and enter the following commands:

   `npm install -g firebase-tools`

   `firebase login --no-localhost`

   `firebase init`
3. `Firebase deploy` to push updates out to your Firebase.